# a counter-example of a holomorphic extension

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Suppose $f$ a function holomorphic on the unit bidisk $\mathbb{D}\times \mathbb{D}$, such that $f$ is $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ on $]-1,1[\times\partial\mathbb{D}$, and has holomorphic extension on $\mathcal{U}\times \mathbb{D}$, where $\mathcal{U}$ is some neighborhood of $\partial\mathbb{D}$. Does $f$ has an extension in $\mathcal{V}\times \partial\mathbb{D}$, where $\mathcal{V}$ is some small neigborhood of $]-1,1[$, which is holomorphic with respect to the first variable. If not, can we exhibit a counter-example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your favorite $C^\infty$ function $F(x)$ on the line that is not analytic and write $F(x)=\sum_{k\ge 1}P_k(x)$ where $P_k$ are polynomials of degree $k$ such that for all $m\ge 0, d>0$, we have $|P_k^{(m)}(x)|\le C_{m,d}k^{-d}$ for all $x\in[-2,2],k\ge 1$. Then $|P_k(z)|\le C_{0,0}(1+|z|)^{k}$ for all $z\in\mathbb C$. Now define $f(z,w)=\sum_{k\ge 1}P_k(z)w^{k^2}$. This is analytic in $\mathbb C\times\mathbb D$ and $C^\infty$ on $[-2,2]\times \partial\mathbb D$ because all formal series for the derivatives
$\partial_x^m\partial_w^n f(x,w)=\sum_{k\ge 1}P_k^{(m)}(x)[k^2(k^2-1)\dots(k^2-n+1)]w^{k^2-n}$ converge uniformly (just use any $d\ge 2n+2$). However $f(x,1)=F(x)$.

Comment: thank you, can you precise what you mean by the $d$ variable

Comment: @user2478159 The one in line 2.The quantifiers are "For every $m,d$, there exists $C_{m,d}$ such that for every $k\ge 1$ and every $x\in[-2,2]$..."

Comment: thank you but how do you get the uniform convergence of any 2-variables partial derivatives since you need some inequalities $d≥2n+2$ ?

Comment: @user2478159 We have $|P^{(m)}_k(x)|\le C_{m,d}k^{-d}$, so the terms do not exceed $C_{m,2n+2}k^{-2}$ regardless of $x$ and $w$. So what's your problem?

Comment: ok sorry, I read too quickly your instance, for $d$, you control uniformally for $x,k$. Please update your answer with quantifier, since it is not clear. Besides, where does come from the decomposition of $F$ in such polynomial sums ?

Comment: @user2478159 **where does come from the decomposition of F in such polynomial sums ?** Bernstein characterization of classes of smooth functions in terms of the speed of their uniform polynomial approximation, of course. They usually prove it for trigonometric polynomials when teaching real analysis, but who cares whether the independent variable is written as $x$ or as $\cos x$?

Comment: thank you for your response. To clarify your answer 1) could you put one line about your choice of interpolation, since there is no canonical one 2) could you give some references about your estimates which, unless I ma missing something seems not trivial. Besides, the question I raised comes from a break-down of a more general question about analytic wave front set. In fact, functions that verifies the conditions we put has a unique direction of analytic wave front set, and I find it quite strange that any $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function would verify that. What do you think ?

Comment: @user2478159 Just write $F(3\cos x)=\sum_{k\ge 0}a_k\cos kx$ (Fourier) and put $P_k(3\cos x)=a_k\cos kx$. Note that $a_k$ decay faster than any power and $x\to 3\cos x$ is a diffeomorphism of some arc to $[-2,2]$, to get the bounds for $P_k^{(m)}$. The estimate $|P_k(z)|\le C_{0,0}(1+|z|)^k$ is just the maximum principle for  $G(z)=P_k(z+\frac 1z)z^{-k}$ outside the unit disk. As to analytic front sets, I managed to read only $3/2$ of $4$ volumes of Hormander when I was a student, so I don't understand the words. However, if you translate it into elementary language, I can think of it.

Comment: thank you, I postmy answer in the 3 following comments. Of course I understood that you tackle the fourier development. What worries me is the estimate and the behaviour of the leading terms of the decomposition of $\cos(⁡kx)$ in $k$-degree polynomials. But I should be missing here something obvious. Besides, for the analytic wave front set deals, there are many point of views : you can find in Hörmander a definition with some decay condition of fourier transform,

Comment: you can check also FBI transform. Btw, analytic wave front set of a function $f$ can be thought through hyperfunction theory point of view, and a direction which do not belong to wave front set is such that $f$ can be decomposed as a boundary value of holomorphic functions, each being holomorphic in some wedge, actually a cone (in short the dual cone of the cone of wave front set directions). One extreme case is when there is an unique direction wave front set and I didn't find any litterature on finite wave front set

Comment: A simple case, will be to consider function on the real plane which is a boundary value of function holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}\times\mathbb{H}$, where $\mathcal{H}$ is the upper half-plane, which gets to this `SO` question

Comment: @user2478159 If "SO" was supposed to be a hyperlink, it doesn't work :-(

Comment: sorry I meant this very `MO` (mathoverflow) question

Comment: @user2478159 **What worries me is the estimate and the behaviour of the leading terms of the decomposition of cos(kx) in k-degree polynomials.** Why? Have I ever said anything that would depend of the properties of the leading terms? Of course, if you don't view polynomials as a whole but expand into individual powers, nothing good will come out of it, but what might be the reason for even thinking of that? BTW, $\cos kx$ *is* a $k$-th degree polynomial in $3\cos x$. What "decomposition" are you talking about?

Comment: thank you for your response. Now, I understand better. Sorry for all those precisions, I was not confortable with the fact that any $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ function could be approached this way because of the analytic wave front set matter. In fact, the example you gave answers correctly the question I asked, and I think the issue with regard to the wave front set comes from boundary values on [−2,2]×∂. There should be in some sens continuity of any derivative up to the boundary (at least the subset of the boundary of interest )

Comment: these boundary values should be approached by any family of $z\in \times$ converging to some [−2,2]×∂ element, and I suppose this is not true in the example you gave. What do you think ?

Comment: @user2478159 I think that if you spend some time figuring out *exactly* what you really want to ask and post the question in a new thread, I'll think of it :-). Patchwork is never good in my experience though we still *do* have some leeway in the current argument.

Comment: @user2478159 Figured it out yet?

Comment: thank you for staying tuned, I have just created a new question